# In SQL query, filter with where clause on another query result

Tags: sql

I'm not great with SQL, and want to do something that I think is fairly simple. The following query returns a one-column table of IDs:

```
select distinct(email_campaign_id) 
    from hubspot.email_events a
where a.subject in ('subject1', 'subject2', 'subject3')
```

I'd like to use this column of IDs in another query like this:

```
with relevant_ids as
  (
  select distinct(email_campaign_id) 
      from hubspot.email_events a
  where a.subject in ('subject1', 'subject2', 'subject3')
  )

select * 
  from hubspot.email_events a
where a.email_campaign_id in relevant_ids
```

however this throws an error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "relevant_ids"
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong here? Is my use of 'with' incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just:

```
select * 
  from hubspot.email_events a
where a.email_campaign_id in (   
                               select distinct(email_campaign_id) 
                               from hubspot.email_events a
                               where a.subject in ('subject1', 'subject2', 'subject3')
)
```

OR if you want to use CTE, you have to name the column in CTE if no column name is specified, but in your case, it is fine, like:

```
with relevant_ids as
  (
  select distinct(email_campaign_id) --as COLUMNNAME 
      from hubspot.email_events a
  where a.subject in ('subject1', 'subject2', 'subject3')
  )

select * 
  from hubspot.email_events a
where a.email_campaign_id in (SELECT COLUMNNAME from relevant_ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a `SELECT` query inside the `IN`:

```
with relevant_ids as (
    select distinct(email_campaign_id) 
    from hubspot.email_events a
    where
        a.subject in ('subject1', 'subject2', 'subject3')
)    
select * 
from hubspot.email_events a
where
    a.email_campaign_id in (SELECT email_campaign_id FROM relevent_ids);
```

Answer (score 1):

or just join your cte

```
  with relevant_ids as
  (
      select distinct(email_campaign_id) 
         from hubspot.email_events a
      where a.subject in ('subject1', 'subject2', 'subject3')
  )

select * 
  from hubspot.email_events a 
 join relevant_ids ri on ri.email_campaign_id = a.email_campaign_id
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to attempt to answer this question. Please provide more context as to why you are suggesting the asker utilize this code snippet offered.